# How to prevent direct URL access of a file which is used in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, apache

I have an mp3 file in a server, Example: www.example.com/Album/Songs/abc.mp3.

I am building an android app to list all files under 'Songs' folder and then play the selected ones.

Now, is there a way to prevent direct access to the mp3 file incase if someone gets hold of the URL?

I tried the usual methods like rewrite engine.  It prevents direct URL access but it also blocks my app from using the files.

Here's my android code to play the files:

```
            MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            player.setDataSource(song_path);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
```

The song_path is simply http://www.example.com/Album/Songs/abc.mp3

PS: I understand that encrypting through ProGuard will make it nearly impossible to get the direct URL through reverse engineering.  I still wanted to check if there is any other way to make it work.

Comment: `song_path is simply www.xyz.com/Album/Songs/abc.mp3` Hard to believe. It will be ` hlttp://www.xyz.com/Album/Songs/abc.mp3` i think.

Comment: @greenapps: Updated now.

Comment: Does the server run PHP? How serious are you about preventing a direct connection - that is, are you happy to write some PHP? Can you change the URL request at all from the App?

Comment: @Tigger: Yes, the server runs PHP.  I was just curious to find out if any easy way existed as I am not well-versed with PHP.  I cannot change the URL request from the App as I have already gone too far in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing you an do about it in your android app. its a policy the server side should take to prevent this. even if you proguard your APK there apps like wireShark which can sniff your app and find what APIs you are calling.

there are some ways to do this. some try to generate temprory links whenever the app (with a user that is logged in) calls a say play API they provide the app wit ha temporary link that will invalidates some minuets (or hour) later. then app uses that link to play the music or whatever.

another scenario is to encrypt the music bytes and decrypt in the application side that has more complicated considerations.

Comment: On server side, Is there anything possible at all to prevent this?  I tried the options listed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450558/what-is-the-best-way-to-prevent-certain-directories-of-a-web-site-from-being-dir
All of those options block the file for my android app as well.

Comment: what this link refers is to prevent a file from being accessed from outside of server side. any kind of access. like db file that you cant access directly in any way. its something different. what you are looking for is streaming methodologies.

Comment: I followed the same steps (rewrite engine) and it worked perfectly fine for a website.  My wepage was able to play the mp3 when the user clicks the 'play' button.  If the user tried to access it directly through URL, they get redirected to home page (thus preventing access to the file).  I am looking for something similar to this for an android app.

Comment: Im working on a music stream application i went all the way you want to go . We use temporary link generation in serverside and its good. I know that even soptify encrypts the data . These are two standard way to acheive what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `player.setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri, Map<String, String> headers)` to send a custom `header`. You can then check for that custom header in PHP or in Apache before returning the mp3.

To check in Apache, you would use a `rewrite rule` to check for and allow only connections with the correct `header`.

In PHP, you could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_*YOUR_HEADER_HERE*']` and then `echo` the MP3 file along with the correct headers. Might be a bit tricky if you allow seeking.

The Apache `rewrite rule` may be the easiest to implement.